Find the size of the segment between $2$ points belonging to two tangents described below
A quadrilateral $ABCD$ inscribed in a circumference, the extensions of $AB$ and $DC$ intersect at point $"P"$ and the extensions of $BC$ and $AD$ intersect at point $"Q"$.
Calculate the length of $PQ$, knowing that the tangents drawn from $"P"$ and $"Q"$ to the circumference measure $4$m and $3$m. (Answer: $5$)
I made the figure and I try:

$PM^2 = PC.PD = PB.PA = 4^2 = 16$
$QN^2 = QA.QD = 3^2 = 9$
ABCD is cyclic

FYI, in your second set of equations, your $QA.Q\color{red}{B}$ should be $QA.Q\color{red}{D}$ instead. In addition, similar to what you did with the first set of equations, you may wish to add that the second set is also equal to $QB.QC$.

@JohnOmielan I noticed and corrected it...thank you for the warning

@JohnOmielan How do you ensure QBC are aligned?

You're welcome for the notice. By "How do you ensure QBC are aligned?", I assume you mean that $QBC$ forms a straight line. If so, then your problem statement explicitly gives this with "... the extensions of $BC$ and $AD$ intersect at point $"Q"$", i.e., $Q$ is on the extension of $BC$ and, thus, $QBC$ must be a straight line. If you mean something else, please clarify.

@JohnOmielan  Understood...thanks again

You've made a good start. Continuing on, the following is a scaled version of your diagram, with $CB$ extended to $Q$, and for simpler algebra there's also several line lengths from $P$ or $Q$ indicated.

In particular, there's
$$\lvert PC\rvert = e, \lvert PD\rvert = f, \lvert PB\rvert = g, \lvert PA\rvert = h, \lvert QB\rvert = i, \lvert QC\rvert = j, \lvert QA\rvert = k, \lvert QD\rvert = m \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
With the Power of a point, as you've already basically done, we have
$$ef = gh = 16, \;\; ij = km = 9 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Since $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, it's opposite angles are supplementary, so letting $\measuredangle QCP = \alpha$, we then have
$$\measuredangle QCP = \alpha, \; \measuredangle QCD = 180^{\circ} - \alpha, \; \measuredangle PAQ = 180^{\circ} - \alpha, \; \measuredangle PAD = \alpha \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Using $\cos(180^{\circ} - \alpha) = -\cos(\alpha)$ and the Law of cosines with the sides opposite the angles in \eqref{eq3A} above in $\triangle QCP$, $\triangle QCD$, $\triangle PAQ$ and $\triangle PAD$, respectively, gives
$$\lvert PQ\rvert^2 = e^2 + j^2 - 2ej\cos\alpha \\
m^2 = (f - e)^2 + j^2 + 2(f - e)j\cos\alpha \\
\lvert PQ\rvert^2 = k^2 + h^2 + 2kh\cos\alpha \\
f^2 = (m - k)^2 + h^2 - 2(m - k)h\cos\alpha \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Adding the first and third, then subtracting the second and fourth, equations above, plus using \eqref{eq2A}, results in
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2\lvert PQ\rvert^2 - m^2 - f^2 & = -f^2 + 2ef - m^2 + 2mk + 2(-fj + mh)\cos\alpha \\
2\lvert PQ\rvert^2 & = 2(16) + 2(9) + 2(mh - fj)\cos\alpha \\
\lvert PQ\rvert^2 & = 25 + (mh - fj)\cos\alpha
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Have the altitude from $P$ to $QD$ meet there at $S$, and the altitude from $Q$ to $PD$ meet there at $T$. Then, if $u$ is the area of $\triangle PQD$, and using the one-half base times altitude triangle area formula, we get
$$2u = m\,\lvert PS\rvert = f\,\lvert QT\rvert \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
From \eqref{eq3A}, we have $\measuredangle QCP = \measuredangle PAD = \alpha$, so $\triangle PSA \sim \triangle QTC$, thus
$$\frac{\lvert PS\rvert}{h} = \frac{\lvert QT\rvert}{j} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert PS\rvert = \frac{h}{j}\lvert QT\rvert \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
Substituting this into \eqref{eq6A} gives
$$\frac{mh}{j}\lvert QT\rvert = f\,\lvert QT\rvert \;\;\to\;\; mh = fj \;\;\to\;\; mh - fj = 0 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
Finally, using this in \eqref{eq5A} leads to
$$\lvert PQ\rvert^2 = 25 \;\;\to\;\; \lvert PQ\rvert = 5 \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

As Piquito's comment indicates, in the second line of my \eqref{eq5A}, replacing the $16$ with $\lvert PM\rvert^2$ and $9$ with $\lvert QN\rvert^2$, then since $mh − fj = 0$ is true just from the internal angles being equal due to the cyclic quadrilateral properties, i.e., it has nothing to do with what either $\lvert PM\rvert$ or $\lvert QN\rvert$ are, we end up with the more general
$$\lvert PQ\rvert^2 = \lvert PM\rvert^2 + \lvert QN\rvert^2 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Ecellent, thank's my friend.

@John Omelan: Is in general $\overline{PQ}^2=\overline{PM}^2+\overline{QN}^2$ ?

@John Omielan: A nice property certainly. Thanks.


Hint: Considering the picture you need to show $\angle PVQ=90^o$. For this you may take one of these ways:
1-Showing Arc QI=Arc FL which results in $\angle QPL=\angle FQI$. Since $\angle PQI=90^o$ then $\angle PVQ=90^o$ .
2- Showing that $IL|| QF$; since $\angle PLI=90^o$ then $\angle PVQ=90^o$ .
3- Showing the circle on diameter PQ and centered at E passes the intersection of two circles with radius 4 on center P and 3 on center Q.

There are  infinitely many $(A,B,C,D)$ in the circle giving the same points $P$ and $M$ (in the given figure draw two lines $PA'$ and $PD'$ so you get another $(A',B',C',D')$ and another segment $\overline{Q'N'}$ of lenght $3$. If your problem has a determined solution then you have a nice invariant. I feel It is not improbable that segment $\overline{PQ}$ is not determined uniquely.

Thnaks for help
